# Google Authenticator on iPhone 7 can not edit/remove entries

Tags: google, iphone

I have been handed this phone from my workplace and have to use it. In the past I installed the Google Authenticator app on Android Nougat and it was working in all aspects.

Now I added some accounts on the iPhone side and removed them from Android to prevent confusion. But I accidentally moved one of my personal accounts to my work iPhone. I need to delete it from iPhone and relocate it back to Android instance.

For the life of me, I can not find a edit button or any other gesture that can help me edit/remove entries on the iPhone side. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 4):

In the blue top bar with the "Authenticator" title, on the right you have the two buttons, one with a plus sign to add entries and one with a stylized pencil that allows you to edit the list.

[image: the Google Authenticator screen]

Tap the pencil button, tap the circle on the left side of any entry you want to delete (the circle will fill red) and at the bottom of the screen a button to delete the selected entries will appear.

Comment: This is not helpful as I have no "stylized pencil" to tap.

Comment: On my iPhone ![this](https://ibb.co/h9pznc) is the Authenticator screen. As written below, it's possible your app is stuck... never happened to me though

Comment: Also, you need to be very precise when tapping on the circle. It won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Re-set your phone.  On occasion, the program freezes... and that "blue" bar at the top labeled "Authenticator" will not appear.  When this happened to me, it was a gray bar at the top and bottom.  When I turned off my phone and restarted it - and then went into Google Authenticator, the blue-authenticator bar (with the edit pencil icon) had returned!  I was then able to remove the number/counters I wanted to remove.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS I had to remove and reinstall the app before I could see the blue header, mine was grayed out with no menu available.